# Encrypt the message with AES 256 then Hash the message including Key using SHA-384 hashing algorithm finally Sign it with ECDSA in C#

Tags: c#, encryption

I am pretty new to Cryptography. I have been asked to work on an assignment where I need to Encrypt a file with AES encryption (using Key and IV = 0), once I am able to encrypt the file I need to include the private key in file header and hash the file using SHA 384 once this is done, finally I need to sing the message with ECDSA-P-384 signature. Now, I am able to encrypt a file usign AES 256 algorithm, here is my code.

Main Method -

```
            public void EnStart()
            {
            try
            {
                using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
                    {
                    myAes.BlockSize = 128;  // define BlockSize
                    myAes.KeySize = 256;    // define KeySize
                    myAes.IV = new byte[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; //MIDS will use an empty IV
                    myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                    // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes. + Write myAes.Key in separate file
                    byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                    string strEncryptedMsg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted); // get UTF8 encoded string.
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\DEV\OUT\EncryptedText.txt", strEncryptedMsg);

                    string strEncryptedFile = string.Empty;
                    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Amit\DEV\OUT\EncryptedText.txt");
                    strEncryptedFile = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes);

                    // Decrypt the bytes to a string. 
                    myAes.Key = ReadKeyFile(strKeyPath);

                    string strDecryptedMsg = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Amit\DEV\OUT\DecryptedText.txt", strDecryptedMsg);

                    //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
                    //Console.WriteLine("Key:   {0}", strKey);
                    }           
                }
            catch (Exception e)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
                }
            }
```

// Encryption Method

```
            static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
            {
                // Check arguments.
                if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
                if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
                if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("IV-Key");
                byte[] encrypted;
                // Create an Aes object
                // with the specified key and IV.
                using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aesAlg.Key = Key;
                    aesAlg.IV = IV;

                    //create key file 
                    CreateKeyFile(Key, strKeyPath);

                    // Create a encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                    // Create the streams used for encryption.
                    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        //msEncrypt.Write(Key, 0, 32);
                        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                            {
                                //Write all data to the stream.
                                swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                            }
                            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
                return encrypted;
            }
```

// Decryption Method

```
            static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
            {
                // Check arguments.
                if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
                if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
                if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("IV-Key");

                // Declare the string used to hold
                // the decrypted text.
                string plaintext1 = null;

                // Create an Aes object
                // with the specified key and IV.
                using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aesAlg.Key = Key;
                    aesAlg.IV = IV;

                    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                    // Create the streams used for decryption.
                    using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                            {
                                plaintext1 = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                return plaintext1;
            }
```

// Create Key File Method and Get bytes method

```
            static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                return bytes;
            }

            static void CreateKeyFile(byte[] bytes, string strKeyPath)
            {
                if (File.Exists(strKeyPath))
                {
                    File.Delete(strKeyPath);
                }
                    //File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
                    File.WriteAllBytes(strKeyPath,bytes);
            }
```

Now my queries are

1) I am able to encrypt the file and write the key separately (just to do test functionality). But when I try to decrypt the encrypted file it throws an error Padding is not right. Please advise, what is wrong with my code

2) Once I am done with Encryption, I don't have any idea to Hash the file with Key, please advise a code snippet which I can be useful here.

3) after Hash, I need to Sign this with ECDSA P-384 digital signature algorithm. Please advise.

Comment: You really should [edit] your question to only focus on one problem at a time. Question 1 is completely different from 2&3. When you remove questions 2 and 3, don't forget to include the stacktrace that you get for question 1.

Comment: It's a common mistake from new users here on Stackoverflow. Just separate your questions into smaller, more distinct ones and you will get much better answers (and more upvotes).

Answer (score 1):

1. You are specifying no padding, that is one applicable if the data length is a multiple of the block size and known by both the encryption and decryption methods a priori. Typically PKCS#7 (PKCS#5 is essentially the same) padding is used.
2. The encryption mode should be CBC.
3. The encryption key should be the exact size required, do not rely on defaut padding.
4. The iv should be a random byte string and pre-pended to the encrypted data.
5. There should be a version indicator in the data stream so future changes can be made.

Note: AES, that is symmetric key encryption, does not have public and private eye, those terms are generally reserved for asymmetric encryption such as RSA.

Comment: Thanks Zaph, let me try your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Zaph, I am able to encrypt and decrypt the text however there are some junk character prefix of decrypted text need help here. As well, I know I am not writing this code in rightful manner, please review the code.